# I can't run 2 or more url rewriting rules at once

Tags: htaccess, url, php, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I was trying to shorten the URL more, but I was removing `.php` file extension from the URLs using URL rewriting too. I can't run both at the same time.

Removing the extensions and trying to shorten link from

```
example.com/profile.php?id={username}
```

to

```
example.com/username
```

.htaccess

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^([^\.]+)$ $1.php [NC]
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9-z]+)$ profile.php?id=$1 [NC]
```

Just the first thing I'm trying to do works, or removing extension, or removing `profile.php?id`, not both.

Answer (score 2):

Because your rules conflict...

> ```
> RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
> RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
> RewriteRule ^([^\.]+)$ $1.php [NC]
> ```

Your first rule matches a request of the form `/username` and rewrites this to `username.php`, before your second rule gets a chance to see the request. `username.php` does not match your second rule.

One way to avoid this conflict, in this instance, is to first check that the request + `.php` maps to a valid file before trying to rewrite to it. (Assuming `username.php` is not a valid file.)

For example:

```
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/$1.php -f
RewriteRule ^([^.]+)$ $1.php [L]
```

You can probably remove the first two conditions that check that the request does not map to a file (since your regex omits the dot) or directory (unless you have file basenames that share the same name with a directory).

The `NC` (`nocase`) flag is not necessary in either of the rules you posted. And there is no need to escape a literal dot when used inside a character class.

However, this URL structure is inherently ambiguous, since you can't have a *username* that exists as a file in the document root (maybe that's not an issue for you).

> ```
> RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9-z]+)$ profile.php?id=$1 [NC]
> ```

The trailing `z` in the character class looks like an error (maybe even `-z` unless you allow hyphenated usernames)?

Again, the `NC` flag is not required here, since you are already checking both lower and uppercase letters in the `RewriteRule` *pattern*.